# int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QueryDict'

Tags: python, django

Recently I am trying to save data into my database when I click on the submit along with default user foreign key. But I am stuck with the error and tried to solve by looking on the web but couldn't find any similar issues.

## my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import TimesheetDetails
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.
@login_required(login_url="/login")
def create_timesheet_view(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        print(request.POST)
        if ('dateToday' and 'dayToday' and 'startTime' and 'endTime' and
            'breakTime' and 'weekType' and 'attendance' and 'normalTime' and 'extraTime'
            and 'holidayTime' and 'workContent') in request.POST:
            #post.user = request.POST.get('user')
            post = TimesheetDetails()
            post.username = request.POST.get('username')
            post.date = request.POST.get('dateToday')
            post.day = request.POST.get('dayToday')
            post.startTime = request.POST.get('startTime')
            post.endTime = request.POST.get('endTime')
            post.breakTime = request.POST.get('breakTime')
            post.normalTime = request.POST.get('normalTime')
            post.overTime = request.POST.get('extraTime')
            post.holidayTime = request.POST.get('holidayTime')
            post.weekType = request.POST.get('weekType')
            post.attendance = request.POST.get('attendance')
            post.content = request.POST.get('workContent')
            post = TimesheetDetails(request.POST,request.FILES)
            print (request.POST)
            instance  = post.save()
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
            return redirect('/list')        
    return render(request,'timesheet/create_timesheet.html')

def view_timesheet(request):
    context = {'timesheet_list': TimesheetDetails.obejcts.all()}
    return render(request,"timesheet/view_timesheet.html")
```

## my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class TimesheetDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="timesheet",null="False")
    date = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    day = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    startTime = models.CharField(max_length =10)
    endTime = models.CharField(max_length =10)
    breakTime = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    normalTime = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    overTime = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    holidayTime = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    weekType = models.CharField( max_length = 10)
    attendance = models.CharField( max_length = 10)
    content = models.TextField( max_length = 300)
```

## my error

Any help will be highly appreciated. Last time tried without the foreign key and i was able to save the data. But I want a specific user to save his data and view only his data.

```
TypeError at /
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QueryDict'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.2.8
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QueryDict'
Exception Location: D:\Django\TimeSheetProject\morabu\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 972
Python Executable:  D:\Django\TimeSheetProject\morabu\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.2
Python Path:    
['D:\\Django\\TimeSheetProject',
 'D:\\Django\\TimeSheetProject\\morabu\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'D:\\Django\\TimeSheetProject\\morabu\\DLLs',
 'D:\\Django\\TimeSheetProject\\morabu\\lib',
 'D:\\Django\\TimeSheetProject\\morabu\\Scripts',
 'c:\\program files\\python\\Lib',
 'c:\\program files\\python\\DLLs',
 'D:\\Django\\TimeSheetProject\\morabu',
 'D:\\Django\\TimeSheetProject\\morabu\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 27 Dec 2019 04:35:51 +0900
```

Comment: `TimesheetDetails` is *not* a `Form`, so `post = TimesheetDetails(request.POST,request.FILES)` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `post = TimesheetDetails(request.POST,request.FILES)` line, since `TimesheetDetails` is *not* a `Form`. That being said, it might be better to [*work with forms*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/).

Another problem is that `'foo' and 'bar' in request.POST` will only check if `'bar'` is in `request.POST`, since it will only evaluate the truthiness of `'foo'`, and a non-empty string has `True` as truthiness.

```
@login_required(login_url="/login")
def create_timesheet_view(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        print(request.POST)
        if all(x in request.POST for x in ('dateToday', 'dayToday', 'startTime', 'endTime', 'breakTime', 'weekType', 'attendance', 'normalTime', 'extraTime', 'holidayTime', 'workContent')):
            post = TimesheetDetails.objects.create(
                user=request.user,
                date=request.POST.get('dateToday'),
                day=request.POST.get('dayToday'),
                startTime=request.POST.get('startTime'),
                endTime=request.POST.get('endTime'),
                breakTime=request.POST.get('breakTime'),
                normalTime=request.POST.get('normalTime'),
                overTime=request.POST.get('extraTime'),
                holidayTime=request.POST.get('holidayTime'),
                weekType=request.POST.get('weekType'),
                attendance=request.POST.get('attendance'),
                content=request.POST.get('workContent')
            )
            return redirect('/list')        
    return render(request,'timesheet/create_timesheet.html')
```

But it is definitely better to here define a `ModelForm`, since that can remove a lot of boilerplate code.

Furthermore you probably better use the *name* of the view in the `redirect(..)` call, and *not* an absolute path.

Comment: I would like to work with forms but my problem is some of my fields needs to generate automatically. I will enter my work start time and end time for the day and after checking the day, end time and start time I should be automatically generating form values like my break time, how much I have worked for the hours and also see whether there are any extra hours I have worked or not. so far did not find any js source with forms. If u can help me ill be grateful.